# Join tables to get missing records

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a reference table

```
NAV_ID int
NAV_FRQ varchar(20)
```

values

```
1 DAILY     
2 WEEKLY 
3 MONTHLY
```

And a datatable

```
CUST_ID varchar(10)
NAV_FRQ varchar(20)
NAV_VALUE INT
```

VALUES

```
C1  DAILY   10
C2  DAILY   20
C3  WEEKLY  40
c3  MONTHLY 80
```

I'm trying to get following output

```
C1  DAILY       10
C1  WEEKLY      NULL
C1  MONTHLY     NULL
C2  DAILY       20
C2  WEEKLY      Null
C2  MONTHLY     NULL
C3  DAILY       NULL
C3  WEEKLY      40
C3  MONTHLY     80
```

I tried following query, but this is not working,

```
select a.CUST_ID
          ,b.NAV_FRQ
         ,CASE WHEN a.NAV_FRQ = b.NAV_FRQ THEN b.NAV_VALUE ELSE NULL END AS NAV_VALUE
    from table_a a cross join table_b b
```

Comment: Hi you have to use left join with where id is null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `cross join` to generate the rows and a `left join` to bring in the existing values:

```
select c.cust_id, n.nav_frq, d.nav_value
from nav n cross join
     (select distinct cust_id from data) c left join
     data d
     on d.nav_id = n.nav_id and d.cust_id = c.cust_id
order by c.cust_id, n.nav_id;
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to `CROSS JOIN` to your customer table (which I assume you have, but haven't provided us an example of) and then `LEFT JOIN`. Thus:

```
SELECT C.CUST_ID,
       RT.NAV_FRQ,
       DT.NAV_VALUE
FROM Customer C
     CROSS JOIN ReferenceTable RT
     LEFT JOIN DataTable DT ON C.CUST_ID = DT.Cust_ID
                           AND RT.NAV_FRQ = DT.NAV_FRQ;
```

If you don't have a customer table, then I would suggest making one as your table `DataTable` won't have a unique value without combining multiple columns (and that asks the question, where is the customer's information stored?) and leaves your data structure in an un-normalised state.